# How to manually add Core Data to project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

E.g. what "Use Core Data for storage" checkbox option means when creating new Window or Navigation based project?

How to add Core Data for Tab Bar Application?

How to initialize managedObjectModel, managedObjectContext, persistentStoreCoordinator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a temp project with core data turned on and then copy the methods from the AppDelegate to your existing project.  In addition you will need to create a model file and import the CoreData framework.

Those are the only differences that checkmark creates.

Comment: You will also have to add CoreData.framework to the linked frameworks for the project...

Comment: I did same way and its crashing at line NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Abc" withExtension:@"momd"]; Am I missing anything apart from copying methods, xcdatamodel and adding framework?

Comment: @Satyam What is the error?  Open your own question and link to it here.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra, Thanks for your message. I am adding the model improperly and I identified the problem and fixed it.